# Extract AIC from all models from stepwise regression

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to extract AIC values and the corresponding model formula and make a table.

```
library(Flury)
data(microtus)
mc=microtus
class(mc$Group)

# making 0,1,2 groups
mc$Group=as.numeric(mc$Group)-1

# First, I divide the datatset in a Known (known) and Unknown(uk) groups.

# Unknown Subset Construction
uk=subset(mc,Group==2)
known=subset(mc,Group!=2)
step(glm(Group ~., data = known, family = "binomial"), direction="both")
```

I would like to extract AIC from the stepwise regression and make a table like this (of course, not manually):

```
Models                                                            AIC
Group ~ M1Left + M2Left + M3Left + Foramen + Pbone + Length + 
  Height + Rostrum                                               32.96
Group ~ M1Left + M3Left + Foramen + Pbone + Length + Height + 
  Rostrum                                                        30.97
Group ~ M1Left + M3Left + Foramen + Length + Height + Rostrum    29.31

Group ~ M1Left + M3Left + Foramen + Length + Height              27.1
```

Comment: The step function should give you AIC values, but only for the initial and final models. You may want to look into bestglm package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bestglm/index.html) to compare a wider variety of candidate models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model object returned by `step` has an `anova` component (a data.frame) that includes the AIC for each step.

```
> model <- step(glm(Group ~., data = known, family = "binomial"), direction="both")
> model$anova
       Step Df    Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev      AIC
1           NA          NA        80   14.96195 32.96195
2  - M2Left  1 0.003070711        81   14.96502 30.96502
3   - Pbone  1 0.340784942        82   15.30580 29.30580
4 - Rostrum  1 0.396842871        83   15.70264 27.70264
```